# How to charge a laptop through the usb port

Tags: laptop, usb, battery, charging

I know that there is a way to charge your laptop by plugging a USB connector into your laptop and then plugging the other end into a wall charger as I know a friend with a ThinkPad who does it. I just want to know how so that I may do the same.

Comment: Newer ThinkPads have a power port that [looks similar to a USB port](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91%2BJ4q-2M2L._SY355_.jpg) (it's rectangular and similarly sized), perhaps that's what you saw on your friend's notebook.

Comment: The question is indeed a duplicate, but there is (was) no correct answer still. The question fails to specify what kind of ports OP has in mind, and the correct answer will depend on various options.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot charge any laptop through its USB port. Attempts to do so via converters will very probably damage the laptop.

Newer Thinkpads have a port that is square and the approximate size of a USB port for their DC jack; this is what your friend is undoubtedly using to charge their laptop.

Comment: Actually, it needs to be specified what kind of port is under question. Also, the square DC jack in some ThinkPads cannot (and should not) be confused with USB, it has totally different internals (only one center pin), and no USB cable will fit it.

Comment: Ali, I am saying that all USB ports on products marketed as laptops are not charging ports, so I have already specified the USB type. Furthermore, if you had read my answer carefully, you would have seen I am not confusing the two types of port; I am acknowledging their superficial similarity so that the asker knows how he made his mistake.

Comment: my comment was directed to deficiencies in te OP question and his confusion, not at your answer. The issue is in wide-spread lack of knowledge and awareness that charging via USB ports requires a very special bi-directional power electronics to achieve the "dual-role" function. This is the "crux" of my comments and disappointment with answers.

Comment: That may be, but when you preface a comment with "actually," the tone is one of correction. That is why I misinterpreted you.

Comment: my English is not that good to sense this kind of nuances, I am sorry. Next time I will be more careful.

Comment: It's all good, thanks for talking it over with me.